# stm32 doesn't receive a Rx interrupt from UART

Tags: interrupt, stm32, stm32f4discovery, usart, stm32-hal

I'm trying to implement simple echo for UART on stm32f4 discovery board (using freertos). As far as I understand it should be very easy.
First I call `HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, &rx_char,1)` in  a task. And after receiving an interrupt `USART3_IRQHandler` should trigger. And then in `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` I'll do `HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, &rx_char, 1, timeout)` and maybe re-enable it with `HAL_UART_Receive_IT`. Did I get the idea right? Should it work?

But in my case it doesn't. I'm trying to send a char from the terminal, but `USART3_IRQHandler` is never triggered. Nothing happens.

The code was generated using Stm32CubeMX with Freertos, USART3, NVIC and with USART3 global interrupt enabled.

Also I call `__HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(&huart3, UART_IT_RXNE)` in main function. 
What is wrong? `HAL_UART_Transmit` works perfectly.

Comment: My advice - when you start with new architecture / peripheral / library / hardware try first without RTOS. When you learn how to use it go further. Otherwise you will stack with the simplest tasks

Answer (score 0):

HAL isn't ideal library. You must check registers, if something went wrong.
Your problem is looking like non-working NVIC. Check it, and if it wasn't turning on use something like - NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART3_IRQn);
Or may be wasn't switch on RE register in CR1 in USART3.
Anyway, I'm repeating - check registers.

Comment: Actually no. This is not the case. I just tried to do it as PeterJ recommended. Without Freertos (and obvoiusly it didn't work). After that I just downloaded full Cube project for some Tutorial. Uploaded it without any changes to the board - same thing. Rx just doesn't work. I've tried different cables also. It just doesn't receive anything. It looks like I'm missing something very obvious (pins are connected properly :)). What could it be?

Comment: What do you mean by wasn't switch on RE register in CR1?

Comment: Oh, I got it. No, RE in CR1 is 1. It looks like that data I don't send any data. But I do.

Comment: Huh, if you have oscilloscope, you can see what happen on RX. If not, you can try get data in main-cycle, without interrupts. It'll let us understand where problem, interrupt or usart.